# Relation between volume form and cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, cross-product

Euclidean three-dimensional space (it's simpler). Defining $\eta={e^*}^1 \wedge {e^*}^2 \wedge {e^*}^3$, with $\{{e^*}^1,{e^*}^2,{e^*}^3\}$ dual of the orthonormal basis, and indicating the classic cross product with $\times$, is the relation
$$\eta_{ijk} X^j Y^k = \frac{1}{6} (X \times Y)^i \quad i,j,k=1,2,3$$
correct?

I know it's trivial but I need to understand some mechanisms of volume forms, wedge product, Hodge operator, etc.

Comment: how do you define $\eta_{ijk}$?

Comment: They are the components of $\eta$ in the basis $\{ {e^*}^i \otimes {e^*}^j \otimes {e^*}^k \}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 
$$X\times Y=(X^2Y^3-X^3Y^2)e_1+(X^3Y^1-X^1Y^3)e_2+(X^1Y^2-X^2Y^1)e_3$$ 
then 
$$(X\times Y)^i=\eta_{ijk}X^jY^k,$$
is the correct formula for components.

In the other hand if we agree the **volume form** be $e^{*1}\wedge e^{*2}\wedge e^{*3}$ and defined by
$$e^{*1}\wedge e^{*2}\wedge e^{*3}=\sum_{\sigma\in S_3}(-1)^{\sigma}
e^{*\sigma(1)}\otimes e^{*\sigma(2)}\otimes e^{*\sigma(3)}$$
where $S_3$ is the **symmetric group** on three labels, then 
$$e^{*1}\wedge e^{*2}\wedge e^{*3}(X,Y,Z)=X\bullet(Y\times Z)=\det\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
X^1&Y^1&Z^1\\
X^2&Y^2&Z^2\\
X^3&Y^3&Z^3
\end{array}
\right)
.$$
In the literature $X\bullet(Y\times Z)$ is called the **triple product**.

Comment: I thought the definition of wedge product of, for example, three 1-forms was $\alpha \wedge \beta \wedge \gamma = 1/(3!) \sum_{} [...]$. That's why the factor $1/6$ popped up...

Comment: agree that I also saw that alternative, but is a only a nuance. You could check that the version I wrote works perfectly

Comment: It does work! :) Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: my pleasure amigo, you're welcome

Comment: as an extra let me recommend you the entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra which I found nice and helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using exterior algebra, clifford algebra isn't that much of a stretch to use.  It just relies on an associative product called the *geometric product*.  In an orthonormal basis, its properties are

$$e_i e_j = \begin{cases} 1 & i = j \\ -e_j e_i & i \neq j \end{cases}$$

Elements of the clifford algebra are members of a $2^n$ dimensional, graded vector space.  Vectors are the grade-1 elements, bivectors are grade-2 elements, and in the sense that all of these are elements of the $2^n$ dimensional clifford vector space, you can add vectors, bivectors, and so on.

With this product in mind, you can define $\eta = e_1 e_2 e_3$.  You can also look at the geometric product of two vectors and see that

$$ab = a \cdot b + a \wedge b$$

The wedge product $a \wedge b$ can be written as a linear combination of $e_1 e_2, e_2 e_3, e_3 e_1$, so you can multiply it by $\eta$:

$$(\eta )(a \wedge b) = \text{vector}$$

Typically, though, the vector returned by the cross product is the negative of this.

$$a \times b = -\eta (a \wedge b)$$

You can verify this yourself by directly computing the components.  For instance, $\eta (e_1 \wedge e_2) = e_1 e_2 e_3 (e_1 e_2) = -e_3$.  You'll find that clifford multiplication by $\eta$ is conceptually the same as finding the Hodge dual, and one only needs to keep track of which minus signs are conventional.